# Given a DateTime object, how do I get DateTimeZone in Joda Time?

Tags: java, scala, datetime, jodatime

As the title describe, if I have a `DateTime` object in JodaTime:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

val currentDateTime = new DateTime()
```

the variable `currentDateTime` should give me the date and time in my local timezone.

How do I get the `DateTimeZone` of `currentDateTime` from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `getZone()` method:

```
currentDateTime.getZone()
```

Comment: can't believe i miss this in the API. Thanks!